# How to store variable length list of dict-type objects with FKs in Django SQL DB

Tags: python, sql, django

Let's say I'm getting some JSON in the format of...

```
"fellowPlayers": [
            {
               "championId": 110,
               "teamId": 100,
               "summonerId": 34258805
            },
            {
               "championId": 9,
               "teamId": 200,
               "summonerId": 19923759
            },
           ...
]
```

...that can have a variable # of entries, but always those 3 attributes, 2 of which should map to other tables (championId and summonerId), how would I want to define a table/model in Django to do this?

If this can't be directly done, how would you suggest handling such a situation? My initial thought was to hardcode in a # of fields based on what I expect the maximum # of entries to be (around 11), but that approach seems like it could be improved on a lot, although 11 isn't too bad in terms of hardcoding.

**To clarify, and give some more context:** I have a model that will be keeping track of historical match data in a game. This includes a large # of details that are match-specific, like points earned, kills, etc. `championId` and `summonerId` refer to in-game character used for the match and the player that used said character for that match, respectively. There are only 2 possible values for team id (global constants) and these won't relate to any other table. `championId` and `summonerId` will relate to tables tracking champions and players, respectively.

The problem I am having lies in the model (let's call it a `MatchHistory` model that stores stats for a single match) that actually "contains" the listing of `fellowPlayers`, because games can have a variable # of players in them, from 1 to 12. So for any given match, I can get a bunch of known-size fields of match statistics which are fine to handle, but I don't know how to organize this when considering the unknown # of players, and relating their info to this model.

I stumbled upon [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-users/storing$20lists$20model/django-users/iOQs7qNfqBI/GuS5IlJ4qpUJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-users/storing%2420lists%2420model/django-users/iOQs7qNfqBI/GuS5IlJ4qpUJ) while searching for a solution to this problem, and it looks like what I am trying to do is not really supported by SQL, as it analogous to storing a list of variable length in SQL. *Maybe someone can elaborate on this "incompatibility" such that I might determine if it applies to what I'm doing.*

If any more information is needed please comment.

Comment: Could you add a little bit? The way I understand it, you'll somehow receive your JSON response, and you want to automatically unpack it and store it? If that's correct, is the general model setup in the answer below correct? i.e. you'll have a FellowPlayer with ForeignKeys to both champion and summoner? I think I understand what you're asking but just want to make sure I have the models part right.

Comment: This is proving trickier to communicate than I anticipated. I have revised my post to include more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a [Many-to-one relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

```
class FellowPlayer(models.Model):
    champion = models.ForeignKey('Champion')
    team_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    summoner = models.ForeignKey('Summoner')

    match_history = models.ForeignKey('MatchHistory')

class Summoner(models.Model):
    match_history = models.ForeignKey('MatchHistory')


class Champion(models.Model):
    match_history = models.ForeignKey('MatchHistory')


class MatchHistory(models.Model):
    pass
```

And you will make the queries backwords. Ex:

```
# select all the fellow players objects who belong to other model with pk=1
FellowPlayer.objects.filter(match_history__pk=1)
```

You can find more examples in that link.

Comment: I have revised the OP to hopefully better communicate what I am trying to do. I really appreciate the effort :)

I will try to wrap my head around structuring things this way and accept if it makes sense to use the DB in this manner.

Comment: I updated my answer again. This is the way to do it in Django. You have a match history which can contain more fellow players. That is a one to many relation. And the queries are made backwords. I am pretty sure you can get the expected result with this solution.